# Get display column phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin, relation view, there is a selection to choose a default display column which is very handy with foreign keys.

I'd like to get this column name in php but where is this information stored?

I've searched in information_schema but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is stored in a database called `phpmyadmin`. To obtain that information issue a query like this:

```
SELECT `display_field`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_table_info`
WHERE `db_name` = 'your_db' AND `table_name` = 'your_table'
```

Comment: Locally it works fine but on my website I receive the error: SELECT command denied to user, is this a webhost issue?

Comment: You'll have to grant read access to that database for your web application. You can do it using phpmyadmin for example